# Android/Kotlin search dialog keyboard change icon

Tags: android, kotlin, keyboard

I want to change the icon for the "enter" key on the search dialog's associated keyboard on Android. See the image below:

[image]

Instead of the arrow pointing to the right I would like another icon, e.g. search.

I use an option menu item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/search_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these options for changing keyboard icon

```
 android:imeOptions="actionGo"
```

OR

```
 android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

OR

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

OR

```
 android:imeOptions="actionPrevious"
```

OR

```
 android:imeOptions="actionSend"
```

and many more you can check it out

thanks

Comment: Thanks Shiv. Sorry, I am a bit new to this. Where do I need to change that?  Doing it in the `options_menu` doesn't seem to have an affect. Same in the AndroidManifest.

Comment: you can use this in search bar layout xml code

Comment: Changed in the `searchable.xml`:  <searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:label="@string/app_name" android:hint="@string/search_hint" android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>